# Остроумие и чувство юмора

Tags: лексика

Как-то возник спор о том, обозначают ли "чувство юмора" и "остроумие" одно и то же понятие или нет. Как вы считаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что это равнозначные понятия. Остроумие - это черта человека, отличающегося острым умом, то есть гибким, развитым,способным на оригинальное, непохожее решение. Остроумный ответ - это не обязательно ответ с юмором. Остроумный человек может и не обладать чувством юмора, хотя такое,конечно, редко бывает. Чувство юмора - это способность понимать шутку, не обижаться на нее, а также способность высказать мысль в шутливой форме, с шуточным подтекстом.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, конечно.
Остроумие это в первую очередь способность пошутить, чувство юмора - оценить шутку другого.